# Walking animation misaligned when using 'Follow Path' function

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones

I am creating a walking ant animation in Blender and I want it to move forward using the "Follow Path" function for the legs. However, when I select the entire model and move it, the legs become misaligned. I suspect that I may have set up Follow Path incorrectly, but being a beginner, I am not sure what is causing the problem. I would appreciate any help or advice on how to fix this problem. Thanks in advance!

[Blender data](https://we.tl/t-VDO4EGuOxD)

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: You're making things complicated imho, maybe you should avoid Follow Path for each leg and instead make them move with some keyframes?

Answer (score 0):

The way the rig is built makes this very complicated.

On a normal rig, IK controllers are part of the rig, and ideally have multiple location and rotation origins that can be used and animated through time depending the animation's needs.
This makes it easier to animate because you never leave the armature's pose mode, but also to handle because in such a scenario you just have to put a Follow Path on the root bone of the rig.

But in your rig, because the legs IK controllers are these Bézier curve objects that aren't part of the armature, they will remain independent of the armature.
Also, your mesh object isn't child of the armature for some reason... It is an issue too.

The ideal way to fix this would be to completely change your rig, make the IK controllers in the rig, reparent the mesh to the armature, and fix the eventual issues it might cause. But that would most likely break any animation you had, so instead we will create a new object parent the armature, curves and mesh to that new object, so that it acts as a new root and can be constrained to follow a path.

1. In object mode: <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Empty* > *Plain Axes* (or whatever you like, but preferably an empty object for performances).

   It should be created at the center of the world, which is what we need. I advise you to press <kbd>F2</kbd> and rename it to something sensical like `Ant_Root`.
2. In the **viewport** (not the outliner), <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> your armature, Bézier objects and mesh to select them, and then finally your empty object. And press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Set Parent To Object (Keep Transform)*.
   It should look like this:
   [image: outliner]

Then, you can add a curve to follow. Position the root empty on the first point of the curve, and orient it so that your ant faces the right way, then <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> the curve, hit <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Set Parent To Follow Path*.

---

Edit:

For the IK bones that follow a curve path, bake these bones' animation (f3 > bake action) with "clear constraint" enabled before moving the empty root.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed help. 

I followed the steps you provided and was able to add the curve to follow, but when I moved the root empty from the center of the world, The bone that is set as the target for the Follow Path seems to be moving away from the Bezier object..

Do you have any idea what could be causing this? I appreciate your help! ( Reference screenshot added to the post)

Comment: not sure about it. Maybe try to bake these bones' animation (f3 > bake action) with "clear constraint" enabled

Comment: Thank you! I truly appreciate all that you've done to help me learn.

Comment: My pleasure. Don't forget to vote and  click the checkmark icon in the top left corner of my answer if it helped you.